# Unable to transfer contract ether using call

Tags: solidity, forge

Hi I am running a forge script against local Anvil and Im not sure why but my contract will not transfer ether.

Contract does hold an eth balance, even when testing with very small amounts it fails (error: transfer failed).

```
function test(address to, uint256 amount) public override {
  console.log("TEST: this balance %s", address(this).balance);
  (bool success,) = payable(to).call{value: amount}("");
  require(success, "error: transfer failed");
}
```

Does the above only work with contracts and conflicts with the EOA of the deployer or something?

Not sure what is going on here. Thanks!

Comment: With this, you’re basically transferring Eth from `Script` contract to any payable address. Is your `Script` contract having enough Eth balance to cover the amount to be transferred plus some gas fees? What is the output for `console.log("TEST: this balance %s", address(this).balance);`?